# Changing the first column in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I made a method that returns a data frame based on an initial inputed data frame. The initial inputed data frame looks like this:

```
2021-02-22 714.5
2021-02-23 698.84
2021-02-24 742.02
```

And the outputted data frame looks like this:

```
0 668.86
0 673.47 
0 684.018
```

I want to be able to change the zeros into the dates given in the previous data frame. I pasted the code for my method that outputted the data frame with zeros that I want to change:

```
def (ematwelve(stock)):

days=get_historical_data(stock, output_format='pandas', token=api_token,start=datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=12))
length=len(days)
i=1 
if (length<12):
   for length in range(length,13): 
         i+=1
days=get_historical_data(stock, output_format='pandas',token=api_token,start=datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=12+i)['close'}
summation=0
i=0 
for x in range(len(days)):
    summation=+days.iloc[I](this is supposed to be lowercase, autocorrects from i to I)
    i=+1
average=summation/len(days)
ema=pd.DataFrame([average],columns=['Closing Price'])
k=2/13
i=1 
for y in range(0,len(days)):
    if (len(ema)==1):
        prev_ema=average
    else: 
        prev_ema=ema.iloc[len(ema)-1]
    close=days.iloc[len(ema)]
    new_ema=(close*k)+(prev_ema*(1-k))
    ema=ema.append(pd.DataFrame([new_ema],columns=['Closing Price']
    if (len(ema)==12):
        break
    return ema
```

Thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: you want change zero with what excatly?

Comment: I want to change the zeros with the dates from the first data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `set_index`. Update the example below to your needs:

```
>>> df1
             value
date
2021-02-22  714.50
2021-02-23  698.84
2021-02-24  742.02

>>> df2
         value
index
0      668.860
0      673.470
0      684.018

>>> df2.set_index(df1.index)
              value
date
2021-02-22  668.860
2021-02-23  673.470
2021-02-24  684.018
```